# how to load multiple 3d dicom files and view them over time(4d) in matlab

Tags: matlab, 3d, dicom, 4d

I have 30 folders of 3D MRI dicom images( taken at different time intervals t1, t2, etc). Each folder consists of 2D dicom images(around 30 images). I need to view these as a 4D movie (3D over time). I am very new in handling dicom images in matlab. Could you please help me out with this.
Thank you in advance
Regards

Comment: Are you sure that what you have is really a time series?  MRI exams commonly have multiple series, each consisting of a volume acquired with different pulse sequence and control variable settings to obtain different image contrast.  If what you have is really an ordinary MRI study with several series, the volumes are likely not related as a function of time.  You mentioned T1 and T2.  These have special meanings in MRI (T1 = spin-lattice relaxation time constant, T2 = spin-spin relaxation time constant).  Are you sure that the multiple acquisitions are not just different T1 and T2 weightings?

Comment: Matt, t1, t2 i have mentioned are not T1 weighted and T2 weighted. I have just given it a variable name. what i mean to say is each 3D set (stored in a different folder) is taken at different time intervals for ex, 1st sec , 2nd sec and so on. So what i have is a real time series. having told you this could you please tell me a way to view these 3D set of files over time ??

Answer (score 0):

Convert the dicom to .nii files using eg dcm2nii, then use the nifti package written for matlab by Jimmy Shen
http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/8797-tools-for-nifti-and-analyze-image

then you will have them in a .mat format, you can play around with the data as if it were a 3D matrix.  For our modelling, I created a 4D matrix of 200 time points, 102x102x62x201 which was from diffusion MRI, then I used isosurface and movie make to render time evolution.

Look at the 3D visualisation tute 
http://au.mathworks.com/help/pdf_doc/matlab/visualize.pdf

that will explain those functions.

Hope this helps, no time for further details, heaps of work to do and it's 12pm on Saturday...